# App Service won't Start after reboot by using BroadCastReceiver

Tags: java, android

I want my service to be started when android is rebooted. I used BroadcastReceiver to do so.

```java
public class autostart extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    MyService1 mYourService = new MyService1();
    MainActivity.instance_main.showToast("BroadCast Received...................");
    Intent mServiceIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.instance_main, mYourService.getClass());
    if (!MainActivity.instance_main.isMyServiceRunning(mYourService.getClass())) {
        MainActivity.instance_main.startService(mServiceIntent);
        MainActivity.instance_main.showToast("Restarted...................");
    }
    else {
        MainActivity.instance_main.showToast("already running..................");
    }
  }
}
```

Receiver in Android Manifest

```xml
<receiver android:name=".autostart" android:enabled="true" android:exported="true">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Permissions defined

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS"/>
```

Battery optimization ignore permission also requested in OnCreate()

```java
Intent intent=new Intent();
intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:"+MainActivity.instance_main.getPackageName()));
MainActivity.instance_main.startActivity(intent);
```

But it won't work. Service won't start on reboot. Kindly Suggest me solution.

Answer (score 0):

WE need to register the receiver. Add the following code to OnCreate()

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
    BroadcastReceiver mService=new Autostart();
    registerReceiver(mService,filter);
```

However after reboot it wont automatically hit.